# use CocoaPods 0.36.0 in CocoaTouchFramework with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I would like to use CocoaPods in my CocoaTouchFramework, which has Swift classes.

My Podfile looks the following:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

link_with 'MyFramwork'

pod "AFNetworking", "2.5.0"
```

But how do I achieve to include e.g. `AFNetworking` into my `.swift` class in the CocoaTouch Framework? There's no briding header so I somehow have to import it directly in my swift class...

Comment: Are you still having issues? Have you tried using a bridging header? Need more direction?

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking is an objective-c library. So you need to have a bridging-header and import the correct headers.

If you want to use a Swift library for networking you should look to Alamofire. It's from the same creator. Put this in your podfile:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
```

In every Swift file where you want to use it import the library with this line:

```
import Alamofire
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import AFNetworking, just using in your Swift files:

```
import AFNetworking
```

Be careful with upper/lower case letters, as autocompletion does not work. Import every pod library you need to use, using its name (i.e., the name of the folder inside the Pods group/directory)

Comment: I get ```No such module 'AFNetworking'``` then... don't know what I'm missing :(

Comment: Do you have the swift files in the pods in your project?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AFNetworking pod, try to add an Objective-C class by using File->New->File->Cocoa Touch Class. Xcode will ask you to add bridge header.
In your bridge header you can import AFNetworking such as;

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

If you don't want to use bridge header you should use Alamofire pod.